# Refining Regex for Word Removal in Text Processing: Addressing Space Issues

Tags: java, regex, file

i have regex

`"\\s?\\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z][\\w-']{" + (lengthWords - 1) + "}\\b"`

this regular expression is used to remove words of a given length from a sentence and it works but there is one problem, e.g. "tool that you can use to your advantage. It is, therefore, wise to explore the" we will get " you can use to advantage. It is, therefore, to explore the" how to remove extra space?
all code:

```
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(OutputFile);
            Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-zB-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z][\\w-']{" + (lengthWords - 1) + "}\\b");
            Matcher mt;
            String temp = "";
            boolean firstLine = true;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                mt = pt.matcher(temp);
                pw.write((firstLine ? "" : "\n") + mt.replaceAll(""));
                firstLine = false;
            }
            br.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe);
        }
```

if you remove the space in front without affecting the back, you get another problem

Comment: What do you want to do with the word `here's`? If `lengthWords == 4`, `here` would be removed, leaving you with `'s` that would be appended to the previous word in the string

Comment: Other than that, why not just `strip` them? `mt.replaceAll("")).strip()`